# Why is there a glitch in my superflat world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to do a superflat survival. I go into my new world, but when the world is generating, I see that there are clouds below me under the ground!!! What is happening??? when the world is fully generated, I look up in the sky and I see no clouds! I press esc to the pause menu and did this: Options>Video Settings>Clouds. I check but it says the clouds are on. I think this might be a glitch.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Clouds are rendered at level 127](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Clouds) no matter how tall your world is. You've probably made a superflat world consisting of more than 127 layers of ground.

Comment: no wait, its only the regular superflat. its the grass on top, 2 layers of dirt below the grass, and 1 layer of bedrock under the dirt.

Comment: @MinecraftGamer What is your Y coordinate when standing on the ground? (Press F3 to see the debug screen where you can find it.)